# What's the best technique to code this image

Tags: html, css

I've got this image: [image]

I want to code this image (just the bar, not the background - background can change) using html and css3. It has to be scalable in height and width. What's the best technique to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK you can try this (tested in Firefox 11 only)...

**HTML**

```
<div class="bubble">
    <div class="content">
        Some content can go inside this bubble...
    </div>
    <div class="arrow"><div class="arrow-shadow"></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .bubble
{
    background:#D0D0D0;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BBB 0%, #EEE 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BBB 0%, #EEE 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #BBB 0%, #EEE 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #BBB), color-stop(1, #EEE));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BBB 0%, #EEE 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #BBB 0%, #EEE 100%);
    border-radius:10px;
    border-top:2px solid #EEE;
    border-bottom:2px solid #AAA;
    position:relative;
    width:380px;
    height:100px;
}
.bubble .content
{
    padding:10px;
}

/* Arrow */
.bubble .arrow {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:-12px;
}
.bubble .arrow:after,
.arrow .arrow-shadow
{
    border:10px solid Transparent;
    border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0) rgba(255,255,255,0) rgba(255,255,255,0) rgba(255,255,255,0);
    content:' ';     
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
}
.bubble .arrow:after
{
    border-left-color:#D3D3D3;
}
.arrow .arrow-shadow
{
    height:3px;
    border-left-color:#AAA;
}
```

It's a bit of a hack in my opinion, but it seems to get fairly close to what you want. The only things that may be an issue are:

1. Backwards compatibility. Older versions of IE might choke so it'd be worth testing it and hacking IE compatibility as required.
2. If the box becomes too big, the arrow might look a different colour to the box. I can't figure out a way around this, so you might have better results putting the arrow in a static location.

You can find a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eWj6q/13/

Answer (score 1):

I may not recommend it the best technique but somehow it will work better:

Using linear gradients: A linear gradient is one that gradually transitions between colours over the distance between two points in a straight line. At its simplest, a linear gradient will change proportionally between two colours along the full length of the line.

```
div {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, #000);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FFF, #000);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, #000);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, #000);
}
```

Comment: This just solves the gradient, I'm more interesting in incorporating the right arrow into the whole thing. Because the arrow has gradient as well that should correspond to the gradient that goes over the whole bar. That's the tough thing to do.

Comment: @jesteuvidim how about adobe photoshop? Just [click here](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?l=-1&s=5&o=desc&exc=16&cat=202&event=producthome)

Answer (score 0):

This is closest I could get using div's.

Probably could get the arrow better by using canvas, but it would require javascript.
Javascript would also sovle the background color problem for the arrowish-like box. :)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xvm2C/
​

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwlMj.png

HTML part:

```
<div class="nice">
<div class="arrow-container">
</div>
Hello world!
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
    body {padding:50px; background-color: #ccc;}
.nice {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    min-height:65px;
    padding:10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%, #ffffff 100%); /* firefox */

    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #fff, 0 0px 1px #666, inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #FFFFFF, 0 0 1px #666666, -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #fff, 0 0px 1px #666, inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);    

    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #fff;

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cccccc), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
    font-size:20px
}



.arrow-container {
    background-color: white;
    height: 26px;

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-13px;
    margin-right:-19px;
    width: 20px;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dcdcdc 0%, #ededed 100%); /* firefox */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dcdcdc), color-stop(100%,#ededed));

    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #fff, 1px 0px 1px #666, inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset -1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #FFFFFF, 1px 0 1px #666666, 0px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, -1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #fff, 1px 0px 1px #666, inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset -1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);  


    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;

}
```

​